# Masstransit - Can we use Send req and res for valiating

Tags: c#, masstransit

As per myunderstanding on masstransit

Publish: Sends a message to subscribers .
Send: Used to send messages in fire and forget fashion
Requests: uses request/reply pattern to just send a message and get a response

In my requirement i need to validate my request before calling the Send method. Here the validation should occur at DB level to check for say duplicate records.

I tried to use publish before my send method , but send method doesnt wait for the publish consumer to execute.
My scenario is if (validation is success) proceed with saving data ie the send request job to save data.
So should i use request response pattern here for doing the validation. I am a newbie to masstransit and microservice.

MyTestController{

if(validation success)  // how to validate here

Send request to save data.

}

Comment: Can i get some help in this

Comment: How DB is relevant to `MassTransit` in your case?

Comment: Are you wanting to validate the message before sending the message?

Comment: @drusellers yes, i want to validate before message is send.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to validate the data before it is sent out. Something conceptually like this.

```
class MyTestController
{
  // ..
  public async Task<IActionResult> Post(SomeData data)
  {
    if(DataIsValid(data))
      _publishEndpoint.Publish(new Message())
  }
}
```

1. You can validate the data (like null checking) like any other code before you publish. Nothing special here, so I'm guessing its something else.
2. You want to validate the data using some other data in a database. If its the same database that the website/api is using - that is also not a special thing, so I'm guessing that is not it either.
3. You want to, some how, validate the data is correct before sending the message. But that you need to use the data of the application that the message is going to. That is typically where I see people get tripped up.

Assuming its something like number three. Let's call the sending service "Service A" and the receiving service "Service B". Today it sounds like you are trying to put the validation in "Service A" but it really has to be in "Service B". What I would do is implement a [Saga](https://masstransit.io/documentation/patterns/saga) in "Service B". The first step would be to take request (creating an instance of a saga), then validate the data, then if it passes validation, the saga can take the next step that you want in the process. That should give you what you want in terms of validation before action (we just need to move it to "Service B").

Now "Service B" can expose the state of the Saga at an endpoint like `/saga-instance/42` where the controller takes the `42`, digs into the database, grabs the saga data and converts it into an API response. Service A can poll that endpoint to get updated status details.

Ultimately, I hope you see that there are a lot of variables at play, but that there is a path forward. You may have to simply adjust where certain actions are taken.